Static equivalence of forces and moment

Can someone please explain how the bottom two are equal, how does the bottom F result in a couple with the top left F.
Can't you just in that case say that the two upward forces on their own are also equivalent to LHS, without the downwards force on RHS.

Related: When two systems of forces acting on a rigid body are equivalent?

What two upward forces are you talking about? Which diagram?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

if that were the case now you would have an upwards force twice than before, so twice the acceleration of the center of mass, they are not equivalent


Can't you just in that case say that the two upward forces on their
own are also equivalent to LHS, without the downwards force on RHS.

No.
In order to have an equivalent force system as the upper left diagram when changing the point of application of the force, you must have (1) the same net force that acted on the object at the original location of the force and (2) a couple that gives the same turning effect on the new point of application as the force had at the original point of application.
If all you had were two forces acting upward, neither condition would be satisfied. The net force acting on the object will be $2F$ upward instead of $F$ upward, and two parallel forces in the same direction will not create the required couple.
In the middle diagram to the right, the net force is $F$ upward and the net torque is a couple (two equal and opposite parallel forces) which give you the torque $Fd$ of the force at its original location. The end result is the bottom right diagram is an equivalent force system to the original upper left diagram.
Hope this helps.



You are adding two equal and opposite forces of magnitude $F$ at the point A which does not change the problem.

You combining the original force $F$ with the opposite force $F$ applied at point A, which is a distance $d$ away, to make a force couple.

The force couple does not contribute to the net force of the system since it consist of two equal and opposite forces, but it does induce a pure moment that equals to $M = F \, d$. So the two offset forces can be eliminated and an equipollent moment $M$ applied without changing the system.



The effect of a force on a rigid body can be seen as contributing to two different effects. First, a contribution to the acceleration of the center of mass. This contribution is independent of where  the force is being applied. So in order to have the same acceleration, the total force upwards in this case must be the same in the two sides.
The second effect of forces is to   contribute  to  the object's  angular acceleration, this does depend on where the force is being applied. We describe this using the concept of moment, or torque.
I don't find the diagram very useful, I think it might be confusing, as in the bottom one it might look as if there is some mysterious reason to make the body rotate. Or that moment (or the tendency to rotate) is a thing independent of the forces being applied. It is correct though, but it is an abstraction or a  way to describe the net effect of forces by splitting these two effects into a net acceleration of the center of mass, described by a single force applied on the center of mass,  plus a tendency to rotate, described not by forces but by moment (although the moment in the end does originate from forces).

I think that by "momentum" you mean "torque" here. I can understand the source of this error: in some languages torque translates to something closer to "moment of force" :)

@Amit Thanks, I meant "moment", as he named in in his graph. It might be used in other countries. In spanish I know torque it is also called "momento".

The sequence of diagrams illustrates the fact that a force $\vec F$ whose line of action does not pass through the centre of mass of a body is equivalent to a  force $\vec F$ whose line of action does pass through the centre of mass of a body and a couple (the red forces in your diagram).
The force acting at the centre of mass produces translational acceleration of the centre of mass of the body but no rotation of the body.
A couple is a pair of equal magnitude parallel forces acting in opposite directions (red forces in your diagram, and not colinear.
The couple produces a rotational acceleration of the body about its centre of mass but no translational acceleration of the centre of mass.
A couple has the property that the torque produced by it is independent of any axis about which the torque is measured.
Try it and see using the diagram below.
.
You should find that the torque due to the two forces is $Fd$ clockwise about $A,\,B,\,D,\,E$ and $X$.

Couple can only be produced by forces in opposite direction as the torque produced each of the force has to be in same sense of rotation .
what we have done is added a force in upward and downward direction which does not change our overall external forces hence the first two images are equivalent.(this is done for sole purpose of simplification of mechanical systems)
2nd and 3rd images are the same so equivalent.
4th image: the equation is M=Fd where M is the torque which is calculated by taking a point which bisects the line d. let that point be k , if we calculate torque of top left and bottom right force about point k it will add up to Fd . this can be also done simply by couple moment which is given by F(force)*d(distance between two opposite force).
so 4th and 3rd are also equivalent as we just removed the couple force and added their moment(combined torque) in the the image.

The force vectors $\vec{F}$ are not fixed in space, but you also need the position vector $\vec{r}$ where the force is applied.
